# Splitting Symfony REST API and Backend

Tags: api, backend, fosrestbundle, symfony-3.4

For a mobile application project I need a REST API that I'm going to do with FOSRestBundle and I need a backend website to manage the database (CRUD)

How can I do to have only one instance of each entity? should I create 2 projects or 2 Bundles?

Answer (score 0):

It is better you create 2 bundles. and create all entity In one of them.
For example, create AdminBundle and AppBundle .use AppBundle for frontend .and AdminBundle for Backend and API.All entity creates in AdminBundle.

Even you can manage events or requests by building different controls. for example, you can have a bundle and create ApiController, FrontController,...

I think making two projects is the worst solution

Answer (score 0):

I can say what i will do in this case.

1. Create 1 RESTFUL API project without any frontend part.
2. Create SPA (React.js, Vue.js, Angular) website for admin
3. Create SPA frontend website for users.

You can take a look at https://api-platform.com/ to get more understanding how it should be.

UPD.: If you think about splitting API project to microservice and can not make choice if you need it or not I can help you. You need it if you have many teams who need to deliver tasks in parallel. If you work alone or with small team you can work with monolith.